# calling values from JSON associative array in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, object, associative-array

I'm attempting to call values from a JSON associative array.  I'm finding difficulties as my object is wrapped in "[ ]".  For instance:

```
var scifi = [
    {
        "Show":"TNG",
        "Ship":"Enterprise",
        "Captain":"Picard"
    },
    {
        "Show":"BSG",
        "Ship":"Galactica",
        "Captain":"Adama"
    },
    {
        "Show":"Firefly",
        "Ship":"Serenity",
        "Captain":"Reynolds"
    }
]
```

So for instance before I was assuming that in order to call out Adama I would use the command

```
scifi.Captain[1]
```

However that seems to be outright failing.  Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT-----------

I'm thinking part of the problem may be in the ajax I'm using.

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/scifishows.php',
    type: 'POST',
    //dataType: 'json',
    data:
        {
            show: fav_show
        },
    success: function(output)
        {
            alert(output[1].Captain);

        }
});
```

And this is the php code that causes the brackets, which loops through the mysql results and and places them in a single object.  This is of course called by the above ajax.

```
$all = array();
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
    $all[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: what do you get from a print_r($all) after the while loop is finished?

Comment: i echo'ed that in the php, and the ajax kicked back nothing.  so I'm guessing it caused an error somewhere in the PHP.  Just to be sure it wasn't the JS I tried it w Richard's recommended "scifi[1].Captain" format to call the object as well as "scifi" to call the whole object.  Both methods yielded nothing.  Thanks :)

Comment: Figured it out.  Richard's answer was what I needed, and I was not specifying **dataType: "json"** in the ajax call.  Being sensitive to the single and double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` denotes arrays in JSON, and `{}`, likewise, denote objects.

So at least in your example, since it's of the form `[{},{},...]`, you have to access by array first, then the object.

```
// something like
var foo = scifi[1].Captain;
```

Note that what you have is **not** an associative array at all (for what definition an "associative array" has in Javascript at least).

To have something akin to an associative array, you'd still use objects:

```
var scifi = {
    TNG : {
        Ship : 'Enterprise',
        Captain : 'Picard'
    },
    BSG : {
        Ship : 'Galactica',
        Captain : 'Adama'
    },
    Firefly : {
        Ship : 'Serenity',
        Captain : 'Reynolds'
    }
};
```

Then you'd be able to access that like:

```
var foo = scifi.TNG.Captain;   // Picard
var bar = scifi.BSG.Ship;      // Galactica
```

If you **really** have to work with the format you have, but would like to work with the format I've given, then you can just convert your original data:

```
var new_scifi = {};
$.each(scifi, function (i,v) {
    new_scifi[v.Show] = {
        Ship = v.Ship,
        Captain = v.Captain
    };
});

console.log(new_scifi.Firefly.Captain);  // Reynolds
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the details.  I tried your first suggestion, making "var foo = scifi[1].Captain;" and it just spat out "undefined".  I prob don't have to work in this format with the brackets.  I am just doing it was the best way I knew to loop through all the mysql results and dump them into an object.  I'll attach that code to the top as well.  Any other method would be welcome.